# Hadoop logs - value of environment variable, HADOOP_LOG_DIR?

Tags: logging, hadoop

Can any one tell me, how to get the value set in my CDH cluster for the

```
environment variable, HADOOP_LOG_DIR ?
```

Thanks a lot, i need to know it very badly...

or, can anyone tell me, how to get the log file location on tasktracker for my job just executed!

i dont have access to UI, hence i need the location of log file in tasktracker, to view it from my unix terminal!!

any help pls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value for the environment variable `HADOOP_LOG_DIR` would be `${HADOOP_HOME}/logs`. You will the correct value by checking the file  hadoop-env.sh in HADOOP-CONF_DIR (/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh).

If the installation is done rpm or deb then the log directory would be `/var/log/hadoop`

There are two kinds of logs in tasktracker, tasktracker daemon's logs and Task's logs which can be found in tasktracker's log directory. There is no commands for getting tasktracker daemon's logs, However Individual task logs(Stdout,Stderr etc.) can be accessed Via Tasktracker's webui

Comment: thank you ...  is there any command that i can get the correct value ?

Comment: Also, if we want to access the logs from edge node, do we need to provide particular task trackers ip and port number also... ?

my question is... thru which command i need to access the log files saved in tasktracker ?

Comment: Hope I have answered your question, If you find this answer useful accept the answer by clicking tick symbol on left side